# Antd date picker - how to stop showing date value like placeholder on hovering picker panel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, datepicker, antd

I have selected 16th date but on hovering over date picker panel currently hovering date shows like placeholder, i need to stop this default feature of antd plugin and how date on field after select only

[Image of antd datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trc5k.png)